# Email Verification in laravel 5.7 for admin guard

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, auth-guard

I want to implement must verify in admin routes, i have admin guard and all routes related to admin, how can i achieve this functionality for admin guard in Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I got it to work for me.

1. Create a custom middleware class and name it what you want, in my case, I named it *AdminEmailIsVerified*

   ```
   class AdminEmailIsVerified extends EnsureEmailIsVerified
   {
     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
        if (! $request->user('admin') ||
           ($request->user('admin') instanceof Admin &&//MustVerifyEmail &&
               ! $request->user('admin')->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
           return $request->expectsJson()
               ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
               : Redirect::route('admin.verification.notice');
         }
         return $next($request);
       }
   }
   ```

Kindly note that `instance of MustVerifyEmail` did not work that is why I went with *Admin* model.

2. Register it in your kernel as always,

   ```
   'admin.verified' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminEmailIsVerified::class,
   ```

   in the *$routesMiddlewareGroup*

   I hope this helps

[Admin Dashboard - Email Verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFrd9.png)

Answer (score 2):

In laravel6, laravel7, we can do it by passing route name in middleware parameter. For example:

```
Route::middleware('verified:admin.verification.notice')->get('/', 'AdminController@home')->name('home');
```

Here "dashboard.verification.notice" is the name of verify email route for my admin guard.

===================================================================

Explanation:

Take a look on "handle" method of "EnsureEmailIsVerified" middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
{
    if (! $request->user() ||
        ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
        ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
        return $request->expectsJson()
                ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                : Redirect::route($redirectToRoute ?: 'verification.notice');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

It's 3rd parameter take the $redirectToRoute name

Comment: The answer by anabeto93 works but this is the correct and the recommended way of doing it thanks

Comment: This works fine for Laravel 7. It is better than creating a middleware just to redirect to user to a custom route.